# "Optimal Disjoint Decomposition" of a Boolean Lattice Subset?

Tags: boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

I am looking for the name (and, possibly, an efficient solution) of the following problem:

Given a Boolean lattice $(L, \sqcap, \sqcup)$ with least element $0$, and a finite subset $X \subseteq L$, find a *minimal* set $Y \subseteq L$ such that

- $\forall y_1, y_2 \in Y: y_1 \sqcap y_2 = 0$
- $\forall x \in X: \exists Y' \subseteq Y: \bigsqcup Y' = x$
- $\bigsqcup X = \bigsqcup Y$

If L is a subset lattice, then this problem is a version of the "set basis problem" with an additional disjointness requirement. However, it should be generalizable to Boolean lattices.

An efficient algorithm to calculate a disjoint set basis is to enumerate all elements in $\bigcup X$, and compute the equivalence relation of elements which occur in exactly the same set of elements in $X$. However, this algorithm is only efficient because the representation of sets is not succinct. If we, on the other hand, consider BDDs as a model for Boolean formulae, each element of $X$ may represent exponentially many "atoms" (formulae with a unique satisfying assignment) of $L$.

The following (naive) algorithm should suffice to solve the problem in the general setting:

- Let $X = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$
- Initialize $Y := \emptyset$
- For $k = n, \ldots, 1$:

  - For each $X' \subseteq X$ such that $|X'| = k$:

    - Let $y := \sqcap X'$
    - If $y \neq 0$:

      - $Y := Y \cup \{y\}$
      - For all $i = 1, \ldots, n$:

        - $x_i := x_i \sqcap y^\complement$

However, clearly enumerating over all subsets of $X$ is inefficient. It is not hard to come up with some engineering tweaks, but what I am rather looking for is a name for this problem to start researching about it.

Many thanks!

Comment: Set-basis is NP-complete right? Given that what you've described is a more general version, then why would you expect there to be a fast algorithm? (Or are you looking for a faster, yet still super-polynomial solution?)

Comment: If the basis elements are required to be pairwisely disjoint, set basis can be solved efficiently. Also, the above problem can be solved efficiently for certain other lattices (e.g., for intervals, by considering all interval endpoints in sorted order). So in part I am looking for a more efficient (if any) implementation for the general problem, but also for some further reading material on this problem. It does not seem that exotic to me that I'd assume noone has ever thought about it...